Помогите с ключом для приложения в терминале
[]
Помогите пожалуйста с ошибкой
Я хочу подписать приложение по гайду https://yandex.ru/video/preview/9948503358292896577 я все сделал до того момента когда меня просят пароль в терминале я его ввожу но у меня нечего не показывается и после я нажимаю Enter и у меня показывается эта ошибка (пароль правильно ввожу). Что я делаю не так?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками. // если вы вводите пароль, то, естественно, ничего отображаться и не должно. мало ли кто в это время смотрит на ваш экран. странно не обладать такими элементарными понятиями о безопасности.

"Отказано в доступе" -- прав у терминала нет на файл с ключами.
